# Guava's AsyncEventBus in tests

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, events, guava

In our code messages travelling on guava's `AsyncEventBus` are frequently used. Now, in some of the tests some message traffic needs to finish, before assert on the state of the testee (say, some loads are scheduled on the `EventBus`, and these need to finish, so that we can test if things were loaded correctly).

Unfortunately, at the moment this is handled by the horrible `Thread.sleep(delay);` approach; very fragile and making tests flaky.

What would be the proper way to test code depending on completion of operations on common `AsyncEventBus`?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in end-to-end or integration tests (multiple threads involved) where I need to wait until an event occurred is using a `CountDownLatch`. I would stay far away from sleeping threads as you've already mentioned.

This requires that in your test code you can hook the `CountDownLatch.countDown()` method into the callback method the `EventBus` is going to call. I explain that with a short example:

```
class SomeEventReceiver {
   ...
   @Subscribe public void doSomethingFoo(BarEvent e) {
      // your logic
   }
   ...
}

// Unit test
...
CountDownLatch readyToAssert = new CountDownLatch(1); // could be 2 or more depending on your needs
SomeEventReceiver rec = new SomeEventReceiver(...) { // create an anonymous subclass
   @Subscribe
   @Override
   public void doSomethingFoo(BarEvent e) { // override super method
      super.doSomethingFoo(e); // execute super method's logic
      readyToAssert.countDown(); // signal your test method that it's ready to assert
   }
}
// put your events on the event bus and do all other necessary things
...
readyToAssert.await(); // JUnit thread is blocked until event handlers where called
assertXXX(...); // assert whatever needs to be asserted
```

That's my firsthand approach when testing. Obviously it's easier to do if the to-be-tested classes are designed in a testfriendly manner.

Hope that helped!